Если разные условия else if будут true, выполнится только первый else if или все, попадающие под условия?
Вот, например, такой код:
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
if (a > 10) {
// не выполнится
}
else if (a > 0 && a < 10 && b > 5 && b < 10) {
// должен выполниться
}
else if (a > 0 && a < 20 && b >= 7 && b <= 20) {
// a и b попадают под условие, но выполнится ли этот блок?
}
else if (a > 10 && a <= 100) {
// не должен выполниться
}
else if (a == 5 && b == 7) {
// выполнится ли этот блок?
}

В моём проекте вычисления посложнее будут, этот простой пример лишь для наглядного объяснения вопроса
И ещё такой вопрос. Если, допустим, каким-то образом в одном из верхних блоков else if (или просто if) изменится значение переменной, которая в следующем else if должна была вернуть false, на значение, которое при проверке возвращает true, выполнится ли этот блок?
Пример:
int a = 5;
if (a < 10) {
a = 15;
}
else if (a == 15) {
a = 25; //изначально этот блок не должен был выполниться, но в if была изменена переменная a. Выполнится ли блок?
}
else if (a == 25) {
// выполнится ли этот блок?
}


Какое первое условие вернет true, то и отработает. Остальные отрабатывать уже не будут. Ровно для этого и есть else(иначе). Вот если пачку условий в последовательные if поставить, то тогда будет проверка в каждом. Ну и собственно, а что вам мешает в каждый блок добавить console.log() и посмотреть, как это будет работать на практике?

Компьютера под рукой сейчас нет) Обычно я так и проверяю все свои вопросы - практическим методом, никого не спрашивая

А так - спасибо большое за ответ!)

Стоит ли удалять этот вопрос или оставить для тех, кто в будущем будет искать подобное (вдруг такие будут) ?

Да как хотите. Я бы удалил )

В копилку ваших будущих экспериментов и знаний. Если вдруг у вас возникнет необходимость в проверке нескольких условий и выполнения ряда действий, то для этого можно воспользоваться конструкцией switch (true) { case x > 10: ... case x < 100: ... } , если отказаться от break в нужных местах.

@stylok не вводите в заблуждение. Если отказаться от break, то будут выполнены все case ниже до первого break. При чем, даже если в самом case условие вернуло бы false

@SwaD я это и сказал! Если отказаться от break в нужных местах, то при желании можно выполнить несколько условий. Допустим у меня задача именно проверить соответствие всем сравнениям и вывести в консоль, а не манипулировать этой переменной. Я же не призывал его отказаться от break. )

@SwaD впрочем, если вы хотите сказать, что я не понимаю что говорю, то поспорьте с простым примером, где всё выполняется согласно логике true/false  —  тыц. Вы  где-то видите выполнение в первом условии?

Для чего по-твоему нужен else? Если условие истинно, то else не выполняется и наоборот. Если хочешь проверять все условия, выкинь else и оставь только if. В таком случае каждое условие будет проверяться с актуальным значением переменной, в отличие от параметра switch.


var x = 10

if (x) console.log(1)
else console.log(2)

if (x) console.log(3)
else if (x) console.log(4)

if (x) console.log(5)
if (x) console.log(6)

if (x) { x = 0; console.log(7) }
if (x) console.log(8)

if (x) console.log(9)
else console.log(10)




В JS нет оператора else if. У вас внутри блока else написан if и т.д.
Если ваш код можно переписать вот так с отступами, то возможно станет немного понятнее что будет выполнятся, а что нет:
var a = 5;
var b = 7;

if (a > 10) {
    // ...
} else { // условие в if не выполнено — заходим в else
    if (a > 0 && a < 10 && b > 5 && b < 10) {
        // выполнится
    } else { // сюда выполнение уже не зайдёт, соответственно
             // всё что внутри этого else не будет выполнятся
        if (a > 0 && a < 20 && b >= 7 && b <= 20) {
            // ...
        } else {
            if (a > 10 && a <= 100) {
                // ...
            } else {
                if (a == 5 && b == 7) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    } // тут заканчивается else
}


Как это нет? Есть else if и вполне себе работает, проверял не раз

Стоп, Вы имели в виду, что else if так работает в JS. Теперь, кажется, понял, спасибо

@Денис if(..) {..} else if(..) это на самом деле if(..) {..} else { if(..) ... }, просто когда оператор после if или else один, то можно не ставить фигурные скобки (но лучше ставить всегда).

@Денис конкретно ваш пример похож на питоновский if .. elif так возможно его писал питонист. К счастью он по сути работает точно так же как в питоне.

Понял, спасибо. Не, я к питону отношения не имею, всю жизнь на JS пишу) В принципе, я догадывался, что так и есть, но проверить не мог - компа под рукой не было


Выполняется только первый else if, условие в котором верно.

Выполнится только 1 из череды if или elif


